# Unable to play .m3u8 links in Apple devices

Tags: ios, streaming, m3u8

I have created a live stream that works fine in Windows and Android browsers. However, its not working in any apple devices. Even when I am trying the direct m3u8 links its not working.

One of my friend told me to add the mime type for m3u8 and I added in my server, but it still not working. Can anybody please help me.

Comment: This does not look a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Try asking on super user community